# What’s the meaning of ‘cross one’s fingers in one’s mouth’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I learned an idiom ‘cross one’s finger’ generally means hoping someone’s success by a crossing-fingers gesture.

By the way, I came across a little unconvinced part in the Japanese translation of *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*.

> Hermione stood up, her crossed fingers in her mouth, as Harry streaked toward the ground like a bullet.

The Japanese translation says like Hermione actually put her crossed fingers in her mouth, but I have a feeling the meaning is such that she just mumbled “Good luck, Harry.” or something in her mouth, whether her fingers are crossed in her mind or in reality (in that case anywhere out of mouth). For it is a little dubious to me that putting your fingers whether crossed or not into your mouth is an English body language.

What is Hermione really doing?

Comment: That is probably the result of an incorrect translation.

Comment: Actually it's not.  I looked in my paper copy and the words are almost exactly like is "quoted" above.  The book has *toward* not *towards*.  But the rest is accurate.  *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, Chapter 13, page 223 in my edition.

Comment: I think this one is Too Localised. To *cross one's fingers in one's mouth* isn't an "idiom" except insofar as *cross one’s finger* is. Arguably *put one's hand to one's mouth* might be seen as an indirect way of indicating surprise/horror, but I'm not convinced that qualifies as an idiom, and definitely the conflation of the two is just "creative writing".

Comment: I perfectly understand what this site prefers from the FAQ, but I wouldn't have known whether my question might fill the standard without posting. It seems very difficult for me to post 'interesting' questions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Hermione is really putting her fingers in her mouth as she watches helplessly as harry plummets toward the ground.  [See this link](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_dQmLdEmZ2xY/TL5kEp2lCdI/AAAAAAAAAd8/p52o5paJPsA/s320/ansiedad+1.JPG) for a picture of someone doing just that.  In addition she has her fingers crossed because she *really* doesn't want Harry to crash and people fall back on superstitions when there is nothing else that can be done.

Comment: The gesture is intended to stifle a scream and is in my experience usually called 'biting her knuckles', but I think you nailed it.

Comment: I'd hazard that the sequence was 1) crossed her fingers while he was flying around as a "good luck" gesture and then 2) bit her knuckles with fingers still crossed, but I agree it's quite a literal image.

Comment: Thanks. This question had bothered me for a long time.The scales fell from my eyes.